# HTTP GET response says missing field Node XmlHttpRequest

Tags: node.js, typescript, xmlhttprequest, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to make a get call to Dynamics CRM via the WebApi with the code below
However I get the "Required Field "EntityName" is missing" response. How can I add it correctly? if I include it in the send() as a parameter it gets wiped and won't be sent with it.

I'm relatively new to this so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Code:

```
let url = this._data.OrgInfo.CrmUrl + "/api/data/v" + this._data.OrgInfo.ApiVersion + "/RetrieveEntityRibbon?EntityName=account";

var xmlHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
var req = new xmlHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", url, true);
setRequestHeaders()
req.addEventListener("load", function() {
    let result = JSON.parse(req.response);
             
}, false);
req.send();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but verify it on your end pls.

```
let url = this._data.OrgInfo.CrmUrl + "/api/data/v" + this._data.OrgInfo.ApiVersion + "/RetrieveEntityRibbon(EntityName='account',RibbonLocationFilter='All')";
```

Comment: sadly then I get the error `code":"0x8006088a","message":"Resource not found for the segment 'RetrieveEntityRibbon'`

Comment: @Manuel, this is a function, so should try something different maybe. Let me check

Comment: I just did it with the url ending `RetrieveEntityRibbon(EntityName='account',RibbonLocationFilter='All')` The problem was when I added the RibbonLocationFilter it gave me weird errors but turns out I did write the enum value wrong. Thank you for your help you gave me the right idea